# Embedding PHP in Javascript doesn't work

Tags: php, javascript, html, request, embed

I've got this javascript code:

```
$(document)
   .load(function(){
      $.post(
          'result_source.php?term='+<?php echo $_REQUEST['term']; ?>
        );alert('abc123');
});
```

and it doesn't alert('abc123');. If I remove the

```
+<?php echo $_REQUEST['term']; ?>
```

it does alert('abc123').

Thanks

Comment: You can't call PHP code from a Javascript file. *sigh* You can call HTML, JavaScript inside of a PHP file however. Learn the languages

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the PHP part out of the concatenation. The PHP is effectively pasted in to the javascript page before it is processed, so unless your `$_REQUEST['term']` is the name of a javascript variable you are using, it will cause errors.

Change it to: `$(document).load(function(){$.post('result_source.php?term=<?php echo $_REQUEST['term']; ?>');alert('abc123');});`

Bear in mind this won't work inside external javascript files, unless you create an `.htaccess` or something to configure the server so it parses .js files as PHP before outputting to the browser

Answer (score 0):

PHP will not run in an external JavaScript file unless you create a .htaccess file or configure the server so it parses .js files as PHP before outputting to the browser.

If you put that in a file(with a `.php` extension), in `<script>` tags, it will work, though.